# C# printing shape

Tags: c#

Im new to coding and I encounter a problem with trying to solve this problem.

[image: this is the problem image]

I tried to do the method where it takes in 1 value, but I can't figure out how to take in 2 values.
This is the solution I tired with 1 value

```
        int y = input;

        while (input > 0)
        {
            for (int z = 1; z <= input; ++z)
            {
                Console.Write("-");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 1; i <= input - 1; ++i)
            {
                for (int z = 1; z <= y; ++z)
                {
                    if (z != y)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("|");
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < y; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            input = input - 2;
            y = y + input - 1;
        }
```

Comment: Please try to avoid using images where text can be used, in case the link ever gets broken. Also, you don't provide the code where you ask for input.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. What is exactly your problem? What do you mean with _, but I can't figure out how to take in 2 values_?

Comment: Do you mean 2 inputs when you say 2 values ? If so i guess you just got to put this code into a for each loop. For each input you run this code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement something like this:

```
  int spaces = 0;         // spaces we need to add before the line
  bool horizontal = true; // if we should draw horizontal line

  // we should draw lines of size input, input - 1, ... 2, 1
  // while alternating horizontal and vertical lines
  for (int size = input; size >= 1; --size, horizontal = !horizontal) {
    if (horizontal) { 
      Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', spaces) + new string('-', size));

      spaces += size - 1;
    }
    else 
      for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', spaces) + "|");
  }
```

Comment: Good and relatively easy to read. If for some reason one does not like having both `--size` and `horizontal = !horizontal` in the `for` "iterator" statement, you can remove the `int horizontal = true` from before the loop, and then just inside the (outer) `for` loop calculate `horizontal` as something like `bool horizontal = size % 2 == input % 2;` or `bool horizontal = (input - size) % 2 == 0;`, depending on preference. (Of course you could also attempt to calculate `spaces` from scratch in each iteration, but that will clearly make the code more complex!)